# All Posts admin screen - show time underneath the 'Date'?

Tags: posts, admin

In the list of posts in the 'All Posts' screen, is there a way to display both date -and- time in the Date column?  If you hover over the date, the time is part of abbr tag title, but I'd like to display the time, directly.  I see that I could unset the current Date column and put in a custom Date column.  Just wondering if there is a simpler solution to show the time, since it's already there in the abbr tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code to `functions.php` of your active theme:

```
function wpse_posts_list_date_format( $time, $post ) {
    return $post->post_date;
}
add_filter( 'post_date_column_time', 'wpse_posts_list_date_format', 10, 2 );
```

The callback function receives 4 parameters, but we need only 2.

Comment: I'm sure the first js solution, above, would have worked, but the post_date_column_time filter solution provided more flexibility in formatting.  Instead of returning the simple $post->post_date, I used the get_post_time function to customize the date and time formats.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some JavaScript:

```
jQuery(".column-date abbr").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).attr("title").replace(" ", "<br/>"));
    jQuery(this).removeAttr("title");
});
```

This will replace visible date portion with date and time and will clear the title attribute.

Comment: Please check your script. It does nicely replace date from title attribute, but it does not make title empty, afterwards..